# Как в C# спарсить из строки число с плавающей точкой, разделенное символом "."?

Tags: c#, .net

Метод `double.Parse()` корректно парсит числа, разделенные символом ",". Можно ли каким-нибудь стандартным способом получить число из его строкового представления, но разделенного символом "."? Есть ли способ задать разделитель целой и дробной части числа?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Все эти символы содержатся в культуре `CultureInfo` в свойстве `NumberFormat`. В инвариантной культуре (специальной "общей и универсальной" культуре) используется английское написание через точку, в русской — через запятую.

```
Console.WriteLine(double.Parse("1.9", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
Console.WriteLine(double.Parse("1.9", new CultureInfo("en-us")));
Console.WriteLine(double.Parse("1,9", new CultureInfo("ru-ru")));
```

Также можно использовать напрямую `NumberFormatInfo`:

```
Console.WriteLine(double.Parse("1#9", new NumberFormatInfo {
    NumberDecimalSeparator = "#"
}));
```

Логика такая:

- Если вы обрабатываете конфиги и прочие "системные" данные, следует использовать `InvariantCulture`.
- Если обрабатываете текст, введённый пользователем, следует задавать конкретную культуру.
- По умолчанию используется системная культура, которая зависит от настроек пользователя. Обычно полагаться на это не стоит.

Answer (score 4):

`double.Parse` парсит число в соответствии с текущей локалью. У вас, судя по всему, текущая локаль — русская.

Если строка, которая есть у вас, не в текущей локали, воспользуйтесь [перегрузкой с локалью](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/t9ebt447%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var englishCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
var russianCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU");
var d1 = double.Parse("1.2", englishCulture);
var d2 = double.Parse("1,2", russianCulture);
```

Обычно ваша программа не знает, какая будет текущая системная локаль, поэтому если вы знаете, что данные будут в «английском» формате (через точку), то лучше читать их с явным указанием локали.

Если же вы читаете данные от пользователя, имеет смысл ожидать их в системной локали. (Но в случае данных от пользователя вам нужно, наверное, не `double.Parse`, а `double.TryParse`.)

Answer (score 1):

Так же можно задать `CultureInfo` для всего потока, тогда выполненные в нем методы `double.Parse` будут использовать ее:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU");
Console.WriteLine(double.Parse("9,99"));
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
Console.WriteLine(double.Parse("9.99"));
```

---

Чтобы `CultureInfo` поменялась для всех потоков можно использовать [CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU");
```

Изменение этого свойства приведет к тому, что `CultureInfo` поменяется у всех существующих потоков в текущем домене, если их `CultureInfo` не была задана явно.

Comment: Хм. А как это сработает с async/await?

Comment: И кажется вы при этом [теряете пользовательские предпочтения](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ddietric/archive/2008/02/05/yacvcp-yet-another-currentculture-vs-currentuiculture-post.aspx) насчёт формата данных, которые он хочет видеть в UI. Это как бы не очень правильно.

Comment: Да, с async/await это будет работать не очень хорошо, т.к. у каждого потока своя культура. И да, пользовательские предпочтения могут потеряться. Но, если это простое однопоточное приложение занимающееся парсингом каких-нибудь файлов такой вариант будет проще для применения. У всего есть свои плюсы и минусы =)

Comment: Это да, для однопоточного простого приложения так будет наверняка проще.

Comment: @VladD Немного дополнил ответ. Таким образом можно решить проблему с async/await. Но пользовательские предпочтения, конечно, все равно будут утеряны.

Comment: Ого, не знал про `DefaultThreadCurrentCulture`. Спасибо!

Comment: Я рад, что смог Вас чем-то удивить =)