# Ошибка в преоброзавании строки в float

Tags: c#, преобразование

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Выберите коэфицент - от 1.1x до 3x");
float k = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
```

После того как я ввёл значение с точкой (например 1.5) получается ошибка

```
"Unhandled exception. System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format."
```

Comment: ¿Еще один вопрос про использование `,`  в качестве разделителя дробной части?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/461406/220553

Comment: Ой, спасибо. Не знал что нужно использовать запятую а не точку

Comment: @Nikichka_Dev разделитель зависит от системных настроек либо переданного параметра

Comment: Это зависит от локальных настроек компьютера, на котором будет запускаться ваше приложение. Если стоят настройки как в России, к примеру, то для отедления дробной части надо использовать запятую. Если формат как в США, тогда точку.