# Входная строка имела неверный формат WinForms C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-8.0

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double x0 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
            double xk = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
            double dx = Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text);
            double a = Convert.ToDouble(textBox5.Text);
            double b = Convert.ToDouble(textBox6.Text);
            double x = x0;
            while (x <= xk)
            {
                double y = x + Math.Sqrt(Math.Abs(Math.Pow(x, 3) + a - b * Math.Pow(Math.E, x)));
                textBox2.Text += "y = " + Convert.ToString(y) + Environment.NewLine;
                x += dx;
            }
        }
```

При вводе значений типа double, например -4.2, выдает Sytem.FormatException

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/461406/220553